# [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm": What does it do?

Tags: bash

I am installing Ruby on Rails on Mac OS X.  The tutorial I am following says to add:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

to `~/.bash_profile`.

What does this line do?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]]`**

This portion is a test condition (`[[` is the new test command). **`-s`** returns **`TRUE`** if the file `rvm` present over at `$HOME/.rvm/scripts/` location **`exists and is of size greater than zero`**.

**`&&`**

This is a logical **`and`** operator. It executes the statement on the right **IF AND ONLY IF** statement on the left returns true.

**`. "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`**

`.` is short for `source` command. You are sourcing the file in your current shell and not forking a new sub-shell

Answer (score 1):

It checks if the file exists and has size great than zero, and if so, it executes the file.

The file is `"$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm`. $HOME is a variable, usually set to your homedir (`~`), something like `/home/youruser`. In that directory you should find a hidden folder `.rvm`, which contains a folder scripts, which contains an executable file called `rvm`.

Comment: Isn't `-e` checks and returns `true` if the `file exists`. `-s` just returns `true` if the file has size is greater than zero?

Comment: How will it have size greater than zero, but not exist?

Comment: LOL, I know my bad! I will still leave my comment there. Will remind me of my smartness!!! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I just installed `rvm` and run `rvm notes` as a shell command. The output includes besides other useful information the following lines.

> - If you wish to use RVM in an interactive fashion in other shells
>     then place the following line at the end of your shell's loading files
>     (.bashrc or .bash_profile for bash and .zshenv for zsh),
>     after all PATH/variable settings:
>
>   `[[ -s "/home/username/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/home/username/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM into a shell session.`

I guess it is always a good idea to take a look at the latest release notes.

Also I found the "[How to use RVM](http://screencasts.org/episodes/how-to-use-rvm)" screencast very helpful! It also includes information about your question in the first minutes.